# I have an error when im trying to compile an apk

Tags: android, android-studio, compilation, apk

I've been trying to make an apk and got the following error:

```
Error:Internal error: (java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError) org/jetbrains/jps/android/model/impl/JpsAndroidModelSerializerExtension : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/jetbrains/jps/android/model/impl/JpsAndroidModelSerializerExtension : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:363)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:445)
    at com.intellij.util.containers.ContainerUtilRt.copy(ContainerUtilRt.java:179)
    at com.intellij.util.containers.ContainerUtilRt.newArrayList(ContainerUtilRt.java:168)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.plugin.impl.JpsPluginManagerImpl.loadExtensions(JpsPluginManagerImpl.java:18)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.JpsServiceManagerImpl.getExtensions(JpsServiceManagerImpl.java:59)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsModelSerializerExtension.getExtensions(JpsModelSerializerExtension.java:46)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.library.JpsLibraryTableSerializer.getRootType(JpsLibraryTableSerializer.java:185)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.library.JpsLibraryTableSerializer.loadLibrary(JpsLibraryTableSerializer.java:115)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.library.JpsLibraryTableSerializer.loadLibrary(JpsLibraryTableSerializer.java:92)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.library.JpsLibraryTableSerializer.loadLibraries(JpsLibraryTableSerializer.java:65)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsGlobalLoader$GlobalLibrariesSerializer.loadExtension(JpsGlobalLoader.java:128)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsGlobalLoader$GlobalLibrariesSerializer.loadExtension(JpsGlobalLoader.java:121)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsLoaderBase.loadComponents(JpsLoaderBase.java:61)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsGlobalLoader.loadGlobalComponents(JpsGlobalLoader.java:83)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsGlobalLoader.load(JpsGlobalLoader.java:73)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsGlobalLoader.loadGlobalSettings(JpsGlobalLoader.java:59)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.impl.JpsSerializationManagerImpl.loadModel(JpsSerializationManagerImpl.java:38)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.JpsModelLoaderImpl.loadModel(JpsModelLoaderImpl.java:45)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.load(BuildRunner.java:78)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:266)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:125)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler$1.run(BuildMain.java:232)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl$1.run(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:44)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Please post your build.gradle file

Comment: It appears that you have the wrong version of java installed on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

This issue you might got due to following reasons:

1. You might using some library in your projects which are either compiled using newer java version or older java version which is not supported by your machines jvm.
2. It might be possible that your Android Studio is corrupted so reinstalled it.
3. If you are trying to read the serialize object, which is serialized using old java version of new java version, and not supported by the jvm.

Hopefully this will help you.

Cheers